# Load file after being modified

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

So, i have no idea about what I should type to get answers to those questions, I will explain my case here. I have a program, which is reading a JSON file that is being modified. The thing is, I am loading the file like the following.

```
const foo = require('./foo.json')
```

I would like to know how I could reload the file every time the constant is called so I am getting modifications in the file. I tried to use the following to do it :

```
const foo = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(fooPath))
```

But it doesn't look like what I want.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want it to do, and an example of what it looks like now?

Comment: What do you mean what i want it to do ? I would like to load my JSON file everytime i am calling my constant so i am getting the modifications between the last time i loeaded it and now. Right now, i already gave you what it looks like now, it is in the first code rectangle.

Comment: I mean example output. It might help people to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you are trying to reopen the json expecting it to have modified values.

Node.js uses cache on requires, so you would need to clear the cached require

```
delete require.cache[require.resolve('./foo.json')]
```

and then require the json again.